# Solving $x\; \leq \; \sqrt{20\; -\; x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is how I tried to solve it:

By squaring both sides:

$x^{2}\; \leq \; 20\; -\; x$

$x^{2}\; +\; x\; -\; 20\; \leq \; 0$

Thus

$-5\; \leq \; x\; \leq \; 4$

However, it seems that values less than -5 work too. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{20-x} > 0$ for all $x < 0$, and thus $x < 0 < \sqrt{20-x}$ for all $x < 0$. By squaring both sides, you lose information about the negative solutions to this inequality.

Comment: The issue is that $x \mapsto x^2$ is not monotone on $\mathbb{R}$, so you need to take care when squaring. For example, with $x=-16$, the inequality is satisfied, but if you square both sides, the 'squared' inequality is not true.

Comment: Ah.. ok. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for "However, it seems that values less than -5 work too" and +1 for @AWertheim's comment.. well asked.. well said :)

Comment: In agreement with @AWertheim, I point out that “where you went wrong” is exactly at the first step. For when $a\le b$, it is false that then necessarily $a^2\le b^2$, since one or both of $a$, $b$ may be negative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252847/how-do-i-solve-inequalities-of-the-form-fracaxb-geq0/252854#252854). You should advance formaly as

$$ (x+5)(x-4) \leq 0 $$

$$ \implies ( (x+5)\leq 0 \quad \cap  \quad (x-4)\geq 0 ) \cup  ( (x+5)\geq 0 \quad \cap  \quad (x-4)\leq 0 ) $$

Comment: @AndréNicolas: thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{20-x}$ is a decreasing function (everywhere it's defined), while $x$ is an increasing function. Therefore the fact that they're equal at $x=4$ implies that $x\le\sqrt{20-x}$ precisely for $x \le 4$.