# A question on inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

What is the solution set of the inequality $$ \frac{2x - 1 }{x+1}\lt0$$

One answer that is quite simple to get is $$x\lt1/2 $$ What can be the other value for the solution set...??

Comment: $-2 < \frac{1}{2}$ but $\dfrac{2(-2)-1}{-2+1} = 5 \not<0$

Comment: so is my answer wrong...??@JohnHabert

Comment: Yes. You only have a partial solution. There is another restriction on $x$.

Comment: Can u help me then what is the other restriction?

Comment: Did you learn to do table of signs / sign chart?

Comment: no I didnt learn that

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252847/how-do-i-solve-inequalities-of-the-form-fracaxb-geq0/252854#252854). Note this, your case $<0$.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider two cases, $x+1 > 0$ and $x+1 <0$.

For $x+1>0$ we get:
$$2x-1<0$$
$$2x<1$$
$$x<1/2$$
so $x+1>0 \rightarrow x>-1$  and $x<1/2$, so the solution set is:
$$\{x: -1 < x <1/2 \}$$

You should consider now $x+1<0$ and remember that when you multiply both sides of an inequality by a number less than zero you should switch from $<$ to $>$.

Comment: why did u start with considering , x+1>0 and x+1<0. I mean could you please explain what made you think like that....

Comment: If you have an inequality like a < b and you multiply both sides by a negative number you should invert the inequality, that is, if c < 0 (that is, negative) then from a < b we get ac > ab. So, if you multiply both sides of your inequality by x+1 you get a much simpler one, but you should take care of multiplication! so you must consider both cases, x+1>0 and x+1<0.

Comment: Finally makes sense to me THanks!!!!!!!!!!1

Answer (score 0):

With help from @Mone I solved it even for$$ x+1 <0 $$ The answer I get is $$-1>x>1/2$$

Which seems to be wrong so the answer finaly I think $$−1 <x <1/2$$

when we assume $$x+1>0$$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\frac{2x-1}{x+1}$ can change sign at $x=1/2$ and at $x=-1$ only.